# AWS-Amplify: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito

I'm using: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js

Is there any working example how to use authenticated access to AWS? I'm using this:

```
Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
            identityPoolId: configs.broker.identityPoolId,
            region: configs.broker.aws_pubsub_region,
            userPoolId: configs.broker.userPoolId,
            userPoolWebClientId: configs.broker.userPoolWebClientId,
        }
});

Amplify.addPluggable(new AWSIoTProvider(configs.broker));

Auth.signIn(configs.broker.username, configs.broker.password)
    .then(user => {                
        resolve({ code: 200, message: 'Authorized access to AWS is used' })
    })
    .catch(singInErr => resolve({ code: 500, message: singInErr.message }));
```

And if it is OK (it is ok):

```
    PubSub.publish(configs.broker.topic, JSON.stringify(data))
         .then(res => resolve({
              code: 200,
              message: 'OK'
         }))
         .catch(err => resolve({
              code: 500,
              message: err.toString()
         }));
```

But I keep getting:

[Unhandled promise rejection: NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.]

Answer (score 10):

Did you setup auth with `amplify-cli`? I had a similar issue with graphql and cognito. Solved it by going to Identity pool settings and setting up `Unauthenticated role` and `Authenticated role`. I've just used the ones which where created with amplify cli.

I'm trying to recall this from memory so there might be some parts missing. But rough steps are:

1. Go to https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/federated
2. From the top bar select the region you are in.
3. If you have identity pools you should see a table. Above it there is a link to its settings. Click that.
4. In the top right corner, below `Support` there is `Edit Identity Pool`. Click that.
5. You should see a screen with two options `Unauthenticated role`and `Authenticated role`. Click the select boxes and select the appropriate roles. If you created amplify stacks it should have two roles which have words `unauthdRole` and `authRole` select those.

It should work now. That's assuming that you have right identity pool and user pool setup.

Comment: And what you did exactly? Can you add some link on a step by step manual?